# How to do aligned additions without aligned arrays

Tags: c, sse, simd

So i was trying to do an array operation that looked something like

```
for (int i=0;i++i<32)
{
    output[offset+i] += input[i];
}
```

where `output` and `input` are `float` arrays (which are 16-byte aligned thanks to `malloc`).  However, I can't gurantee that `offset%4=0`.  I was wondering how you could fix these alignment problems.

I though something like

```
while (offset+c %4 != 0)
{
    c++;
    output[offset+c] += input[c];
}
```

followed by an aligned loop - obviously this can't work as we now need an unaligned access to `input`.

Is there a way to vectorize my original loop?

Comment: Have you tried `_mm_loadu_ps()` or `_mm_storeu_ps`? They will let you do misaligned memory accesses.

Comment: @Mysticial - haven't tried those functions - are there any docs? - google doesn't show anything obvious and the gcc docs don't appear to have anything either

Comment: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse_load.htm and http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_fp_store.htm

Comment: Do be aware that they will still incur a performance hit if the addresses are indeed misaligned. But that's unavoidable without resorting to very messy alignment hacks.

Comment: Are you responsible for allocating the input and output arrays? If you are, and you know the value of `offset` at allocation time, you could allocate some extra space and offset the output buffer pointer appropriately. Not the cleanest solution, but performant, and not too difficult.

Comment: @JasonR The problem is that I call the function with lots of different `offset` values.  I had actually considered having 4 different output arrays and then adding them together.  I am going to test this later to see if it is any faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving comments to an answer:

There are SSE instructions for misaligned memory accesses. They are accessible via the following intrinsics:

- `_mm_loadu_ps()` - [documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse_load.htm)
- `_mm_storeu_ps()` - [documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_fp_store.htm)

and similarly for all the `double` and integer types.

So if you can't guarantee alignment, then this is the easy way to go. If possible, the ideal solution is to align your arrays from the start so that you avoid this problem altogether.

There will still be a performance penalty for misaligned accesses, but they're unavoidable unless you resort to extremely messy shift/shuffle hacks (such as `_mm_alignr_epi8()`).

The code using `_mm_loadu_ps` and `_mm_storeu_ps` - this is actually 50% slower than what gcc does by itself

```
for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
{
    float* out = &output[offset+j*4];
    __m128 in = ((__m128*)input)[j]; //this is aligned so no need for _mm_loadu_ps
    __m128 res  = _mm_add_ps(in,_mm_loadu_ps(out)); //add values 
    _mm_storeu_ps(out,res); //store result
}
```